# XNA tilemap tileset

Tags: c#, xna, tile

I'm making a 2d sidescrolling game and im trying to use a 2dimensional or so-to-say tileset. My friend gave me some code that he had been using for his games but his code only supports 1 dimension.

```
   public void DrawMap(Texture2D tilesheet, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < map.GetLength(1); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < map.GetLength(0); y++)
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(tilesheet, new Vector2((x * 64) , (y * 64)), new Rectangle(map[y, x] * 64, 0, 64, 64), Color.White);
            }
        }
    }
```

this is where the problem appears, because it's a group project and we recieve graphics from a graphics designer and we have too many tiles(64x64 in size) to fit into one row of texture that is supported for xna(4096 pixels i think). I barely understand the code that my friend gave me and that's probably where the issue comes from. If anyone knows how to make the draw method support 2 dimensions so that i can use tilesets the are the dimensions(512x512 as an example) instead of 64x4992(which my current tileset is at).

```
    public Level()
    {
        map = new int[14, 50]
        {{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,2},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,2},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,2},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,2},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,5,0,0,0,0,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,2},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,2},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,2},
        {3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,7,2,12,13,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,2},
        {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2}};
        overlay = new int[14, 50];
        background = new int[14,50];
    }
    public void DrawMap(Texture2D tilesheet, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < map.GetLength(1); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < map.GetLength(0); y++)
            {
                //http://imgur.com/1r9VUUN
                spriteBatch.Draw(tilesheet, new Vector2((x * 64), (y * 64)), new Rectangle((map[x, y] % 8) * 64, (map[x, y] / 8) * 64, 64, 64), Color.White);
            }
        }
    }
```

So im editing my maps in Tiled and i realized that tiled counts 1-2-3-4-5, not 0-1-2-3-4-5. So if you looks at my tileset(commented away in the draw method imgur link) you see that i have a blank space before the first tile, but this means that every tile has their positionvalue + 1 in xna, which might be why im having issues drawing it, because the tile im trying to draw doesn't exist in the tileset.

Comment: First my bad switch the x and the y order, use map[y,x] instead of map[x, y] to avoid the OutOfRangeException, Second i don't see any image link !!

Comment: http://imgur.com/1r9VUUN here you go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since i don't know exactly how your Tile Map looks like i will simply give a step by step explained example:

**First** let say we have the following Tile Map Sheet

[image]

this map is 8x3 and lets suppose each tile is 64X64 px, to refer to one of these tile you could use its coordinate (x,y) in the MapSheet (for example the last tile has the coordinate (7,2) -0 based index-), or more cleverly you could simply refer to it as one number by counting from the first tile (for example the previous tile (7,2) represent the tile 23)

[image]

**Second** define your Map Matrix

```
 map = new int[,]
 {                            
     {8,8,1,8,8,1},
     {1,8,0,8,8,8},
     {1,8,8,8,8,8},
     {1,7,8,8,8,8},
     {1,8,0,23,4,4},
     {1,8,8,1,8,8}
 };
```

each element in the above Matrix is the coordinate of the tile in the TileMap,

**Third** the drawing part,

```
public void DrawMap(Texture2D tilesheet, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < map.GetLength(1); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < map.GetLength(0); y++)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(tilesheet, new Vector2((x * 64) , (y * 64)), new Rectangle((map[x,y]%8) * 64, (map[x,y]/8)*64, 64, 64), Color.White);
        }
    }
}
```

in the above code `new Rectangle((map[x,y]%8) * 64, (map[x,y]/8)*64, 64, 64),` represent what's called the Source `Rectangle`, that Rect is used to locate the corresponding tile `Rectangle` in the `TileMap`

Comment: So i just tried the code you supplied me with on my 8x10 tileset, but when i tried to draw it bugged out, left me with a white screen and said "IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled" - index was out of bounds for matrix(i think that's what it translates to). So i hovered over the x variable and y variable to check their values and i recieved x= 14, y= 0. 

Not quite sure what the problem is, might be my tileset or something with the code :/

Comment: Ok so i made a new matrix(5x5) just to try out a simple tileset of 8x2 where the upper 8 tiles are white and the lower ones are green, i managed to draw them in the selected order. I will continue to experiment because if the size of the matrix matters, we have an issue because we want our maps to be around 10 000 pixels if not more...

Comment: What is the size of your matrix ?

Comment: I did some experimenting and reached the conclusion that the issue is that the matrix size is limited, when i switched back to our prototype-level size of 50x14 size it began having the issue with the index

Comment: Edited and added more content

Comment: I am looking at it ;)

Comment: they told me to avoid these comments, but idgaf! thanks a hugeload for helping me out! i've finally made some progress!

Comment: Hey Sam, i ran into another problem now, how should i do collision with this kind of map? just stopping the gravity is simple, while the player collides with the floor -> stop gravity. but if im colliding with a wall or another kind of object that's supposed to stop me from moving to the left or right, how should i do that?

Comment: well that actually depends on your implementation, the simplest way (but not optimal) to that is to define some kind of map layers where the walls represent one layer ...at each update you could loop through all the walls rects at that layer to check for any collision ..